# Audio comparison against a model

Tags: java, comparison, transform, fft

I want to be able to solve the following problem in Java - as it is the language I am most experianced in and my preferred choice.

I want to be able to build a model of a sound - such as a dog barking based upon say 100 sound samples of different dogs barking... Once I have this sample I want to be able to record a clip from a microphone and process it against the model to determine the probability that the recorded sample matches closely enough to the model, to determine if the recorded sound was a dog.

I had the following in mind:

Get the Fourier Transforms of 100 dogs.

Get the average FT of the 100 - this is now the model.

Record the sound clip - generate Fourier Transform.

Deduct sound clip FT from model FT to see how they compare?

I am not hugely experienced with audio - so if anyone can tell me if this is the correct approach - what FFT library to use - and what the process is to build an average FT from 100 samples is - that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I've read about FT's several times, I've never specifically used them myself.

However, I've used the library CoMIRVA. It implements techniques that is based on, among other things, FT's to compare music (www.cp.jku.at/comirva). In short, it compares two "audio sources" against each other by comparing the timbre (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre). When i used it it worked well in some cases, and not so well in other cases. However, that was with music. I've got no idea whether it will work with dog barking.

I suggest you have a look at it and read more about the techniques it implements. You'll find more details under the heading Audio Processing. I recommend you read both reports (Mandel and Ellis, Aucouturier and Pachet).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi - this looks like it may be promising! Thanks! However there is no real documentation to explain how to go about using the specific audio processing classes - anyideas?

Comment: Have a look at the MandelEllisExtractor or TimbreDistributionExtractor. Use the calculate() method available on this classes. This method will return an AudioFeature instance. The getDistance() method on the AudioFeature class can be used to calculate the distance to any other AudioFeature instance. http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Development/CoMIRVA/releases/0.36/CoMIRVA/doc/comirva/audio/extraction/MandelEllisExtractor.html

Comment: I tried coding up a quick program , turns out my 2 - 3 second mp3s are too short to be procesed by the mandelelleisextractor, I wonder what the minimum length needs to be?

Comment: Ah, it appears that the default minimum number of seconds is 25. Try using the constructor MandelEllisExtractor(float sampleRate, int skipIntro, int skipEnd, int minimumLength) using   MandelEllisExtractor(AudioPreProcessor.DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE,0, 1, 0). This is what the default constructor use, except from setting the minimum number of seconds to 25 and not 1. Not sure if the results will be good, but it is worth a try :-)

Comment: Awesome - cheers - their docs aint great but I guess I shouldve looked for a non default constructor!

Comment: Oh wow - its actually not that bad - for sounds of 2 dogs it returned These are this similar:-2.905620000800768E15 and for 1 dog and 1 cat it returned 418.02102002 So I am trying to determine what that means - the closer the number is to 0 the better I think

Comment: Infact no that cannot be right - I have no idea how to identify a conclusion from this number. When using the same input the distance is 0 - when doing 2 dogs its -2.90562 x10^15 and when 1 dog 1 cat its 418...but what conclusion do I draw from that - I dont know how to read the Mahalanobis distance

Comment: The getDistance() method should return a Kullback-Leibler divergence (according to the source code of CoMIRVA). According to Wikipedia, "The Kullback–Leibler divergence is always non-negative". I find it strange that you get negative results. Have you tried several samples? Though a wild guess, it might have something to do with the short audio samples...?

Comment: I think the negative samples came from a specific file - mustve been an odd file! Right so lets have a read up on the Kullback-Liebler divergence then! Hmm - so the result is the number of bits which would need to change before the sample is identical to the others. So between the dog and the cat only 418 bits differentiate it. Hmm - i dont know how to judge how close a sound is from that - its all relative it seems.

Comment: It seems for this algorithm to return a correct result - I would need an avergae model of a dog barking - as opposed to just 1 sample sound. but i dont know how to achieve that

Comment: Hmmm...good question. I'm not sure how the "average" model would perform. My initial though is that the "average" dog bark just as well may end up being something too generic? An idea...the AudioFeature can be serialized/deserialized as XML. How about first analysing 100 dog barks. Then, serialize those and save them. When you want to check any other given audio sample against your model to check if it is a bark, then analyse it and compare it to every single one of your already analysed barks (just deserialize them first). Then, take the average of all comparisons (100 comp.) and decide.

Comment: ...since you've already analysed all files and have serialized the AudioFeature attributes, it (hopefully) shouldn't take long to carry out the analysing? My idea doesn't really scale well if you had 10.000 dog barks to analyse against, but for 100 (or 200, 300, 400) it might work just fine. What do you think?

Comment: Hmmmm thats a fairly good call. I might give that a go! Depends if I can find 100 barks :(

Comment: Ok I have taken a look - normal Java Serialisation doesnt output in XML - so can you outline your thoughts behind the suggestions that the AudioFeature objects can be output as XML!?

Comment: I think it may be like this :                                           AudioFeature dogsProcessed = mee.calculate(SingleDog);
MandelEllis me = (MandelEllis) dogsProcessed;   me.write(XMLWriter)

Comment: Ah, can't remember right how i thought, but i believe that the AudioFeature class has a method toXml() or asXml() which will serialize the instance as XML. That way, you can analyse the files and store the "analysed" data for future reference. I'm not sure how much this will save you in processing time, but in might be worth a try!